# OptimisticLockException Ebean even with @Version

Tags: java, orm, playframework, timestamp, ebean

I tried to update a row in my DB using `Ebean` in my `Play! Framework` program. 
Here is the class of the entity I would like to update. 
 
**Transaction.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transactions")
public class Transaction extends Model{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id; 
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_fk")
    public Car car; 
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_lender_fk")
    public User user; 
    @Version
    public Timestamp from_date; 
    @Version                    
    public Timestamp to_date;  
    public boolean availability; // true -> Available. 
    public String status; 
}
```

And here is the metho I use to update it:

```
Transaction transaction = new Transaction(); 
transaction.car = concernedCars.get(i); 
transaction.user = currentUser; 
transaction.from_date = Tools.StringAndroidToTimestamp(dateFrom); 
transaction.to_date = Tools.StringAndroidToTimestamp(dateTo); 
transaction.status = Constants.WAITING_FOR_ANSWER; 
try{
    Ebean.update(transaction); 
}catch(OptimisticLockException e){
    Logger.info(e.toString());
}
```

And if necessary, my method to convert a *`String` to `Timestamp`*:

```
public static Timestamp StringAndroidToTimestamp(String s){
        String toConvert = s.substring(0, s.length()-2); 
        Logger.info("ToConvert = "+toConvert);
        Timestamp timestamp = null; 
        try{
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(toConvert);
            timestamp = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
        }catch(Exception e){
            Logger.info("Exception date = " +e.toString());
        }
        return timestamp;
    }
```

Of course, I get the fabulous error:

> javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Data has changed. updated
>   [0] rows sql

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4):

There are few ways you can handle this.

> 1) Use @EntityConcurrencyMode(ConcurrencyMode.NONE) before class name
>
> 2) Use raw update query.(preferred)

I was facing too much problem because of the same ebean.update throwing optimistic lock exception,  finally I did raw update query and it worked for me.

Comment: @EntityConcurrencyMode no more used in latest version "ebean 8.2.3" (which is used with sbt-play-ebean version 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I can see some problems from here:

1. You are using two Version fields. I don't know if that is alright to Ebean but usually one is enough. Also I think Ebean will manage those fields by itself, so it may be better for you to specify a version field that you don't want to use (an int to serve as a counter or a timestamp of last change);
2. You are calling `update` but it seems you are really creating a new transaction, so you should be using `Ebean.save`

Regarding the error, that exception is thrown when you try to update a record that has changed between the time you loaded it and the update. To find out that the record has changed, Ebean uses the values from the Version columns.

So the update in your code would generate a SQL similar to this:

```
UPDATE transactions
SET car_fk=<SOME_VAL>, ... 
WHERE id=null AND from_date=<OTHER_VAL> AND to_date=<ANOTHER_VAL>
```

which wouldn't update any record and throw that exception.

I'm posting this information because I don't know a easy way to disable optimistic locking in the Ebean version that comes with Play <2.4.x and you probably will find that error again. In general you can minimize it using a version field and using transactions or reload/retry the operation.

Comment: Is it ok if I put the `@Version` on the Id field?

Comment: No. Add a new column named version and you can forget it is there

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative solution to this problem 
you can use:

```
@EntityConcurrencyMode(ConcurrencyMode.NONE)
```

in your Entity Class

This will disable the optimistic locking concurrent modification check
the new sql query will be:

update TABLE-NAME SET PARAM1=? WHERE ID = ?

the EntityConcurrencyMode comes in package
package com.avaje.ebean.annotation;